Why CFI=1 and RMSEA=0 in lavaan
I
ran an CFA with lavaan and received the folloing output:
> summary(CFAmodel_nofMRI_all_output, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
lavaan 0.6.15 ended normally after 48 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        20

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                           360         362
  Number of missing patterns                        17            

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                13.181
  Degrees of freedom                                19
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.829

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                                21.158
  Degrees of freedom                                27
  P-value                                        0.779

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                      -0.415
                                                      
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)             1.000
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                0.495

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -2589.105
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)             NA
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                                5218.211
  Bayesian (BIC)                              5295.933
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)       5232.483

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.028
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.998
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000
                                                      
  Robust RMSEA                                   0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.040
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050             0.984
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080             0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.033

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                              First.order
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  sensitization =~                                                      
    AAT_bias_smkng   -0.024    0.116   -0.208    0.835   -0.024   -0.024
    IAT_app_av_scr   -0.297    0.186   -1.598    0.110   -0.301   -0.301
    IAT_val_score     0.357    0.217    1.647    0.100    0.362    0.364
    EMGcorr_score    -0.088    0.142   -0.618    0.536   -0.089   -0.090
    EMGzygo_score    -0.104    0.152   -0.681    0.496   -0.105   -0.105
    EMGstartle_scr   -0.105    0.194   -0.542    0.588   -0.107   -0.107

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  sensitization ~                                                       
    sex               0.336    0.263    1.277    0.202    0.332    0.166
    deprivation      -0.000    0.004   -0.011    0.991   -0.000   -0.002

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .AAT_bias_smkng    0.005    0.060    0.086    0.931    0.005    0.005
   .IAT_app_av_scr    0.054    0.080    0.671    0.503    0.054    0.054
   .IAT_val_score    -0.067    0.080   -0.839    0.402   -0.067   -0.067
   .EMGcorr_score     0.002    0.079    0.027    0.979    0.002    0.002
   .EMGzygo_score     0.013    0.083    0.158    0.874    0.013    0.013
   .EMGstartle_scr    0.010    0.081    0.121    0.904    0.010    0.010
   .sensitization     0.000                               0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .AAT_bias_smkng    1.002    0.063   15.982    0.000    1.002    0.999
   .IAT_app_av_scr    0.909    0.119    7.630    0.000    0.909    0.910
   .IAT_val_score     0.859    0.173    4.977    0.000    0.859    0.868
   .EMGcorr_score     0.969    0.047   20.695    0.000    0.969    0.992
   .EMGzygo_score     0.990    0.046   21.399    0.000    0.990    0.989
   .EMGstartle_scr    0.986    0.088   11.161    0.000    0.986    0.989
   .sensitization     1.000                               0.973    0.973

In my publication, I would like to use chi-square test, robust CFI, robust TLI, robust RMSEA, and SRMR as goodness of fit indices. I have read that CFI=1 and RMSEA=0 because chi-square < df. However, I cannot find a citation for this statement. First, does anyone know of a citation for this? Second, in my publication I need to explain why the CFI, RMSEA are perfect while the TLI is not. Can anyone explain in which cases this can happen? I found some publications who stated that low fit indices may be caused by, for instance, low factor loadings (yes, as you can see in the output). However, this statement does not fit to the perfect CFI and RMSEA.
It may be important to note that I cannot change the structure of the model, because this model is exactly what can answer my research question. So it would be okay if I could write, for example, that the fit indices are odd because there is no latent variable behind all the manifest variables.
Thank you for any help or recommondation.
Best,
Franziska
